# share windows 10 store uwp app with employees of another organization

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

We recently deployed a windows 10 store uwp app. We can install the app using hotmail/live/outlook sign in and use it.

Some of our users are employees of another organization (using windows 10 operating system) and they are not allowed to sign in to store with hotmail/live/outlook . They use their own @contoso microsoft azure ad account.

I have gone through below link but it only talks about within an organization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store

Is that possible to share windows 10 store app with employees of another organization who cannot user microsoft personal account .

Comment: I agree with @J... It is not possible to do that. Only the users in the same organization could use the app in the private store.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. We can close this thread now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with your own local private store. The linked document explains it all.

You need a Windows domain for the private store to live in. Only domain members can be assigned permissions. You would need some way to integrate your remote users into your ActiveDirectory environment.

This would mean that the computers they are using would need to be uniquely joined to and able to contact your domain controller for everything, even just logging into their computer, and they would not be able to simultaneously be joined to two separate domains (assuming they have a different environment where they are).

A simple solution, however, is to simply distribute an MSIX package and have your remote clients [manually sideload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises) the app.

There are also other options outlined in that document that would allow your remote clients to set up their own local private store and they could then invite you to additionally publish to *their* private store so that your app would be available in both your domain's private store as well as in the private store of the domain that your remote clients are members of.

> When an enterprise chooses to invite you to publish apps for their exclusive use, you’ll get an email that includes a link to confirm the association. You can also confirm these associations by going to the Enterprise associations section of your Account settings (as long as you are signed in with the Microsoft account that was used to open the developer account).

Your Microsoft developer account can then have associations with any number of remote Enterprise clients so that you can publish your application to any number of remote private stores.  Your remote clients would need to take responsibility for setting up their own private store and for inviting you to publish to it.

Comment: That's really helpful. Many Thanks.